# Adjust height to remaining window height on resize

Tags: javascript

This is a common technique and can also be done with CSS `calc()` but I can't figure out what is wrong with my implementation.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmalancea/59wf3msq/)

```
var adjustHeight = function(){
  $content = $('.adjustedHeight');
  $content.height($(window).height()-$content.offset().top);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  adjustHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  adjustHeight();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <p>Header</p>
  <p><strong>This should not scroll</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="adjustedHeight">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p><strong>Only this section should scroll</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code in your question. Your link might be dead in the future.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your implementation. It does what it's supposed to do, the problem is the content is overflowing your container. Might want to add "overflow-y:scroll" to your container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RaduAndrei provided the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449727/adjust-height-to-remaining-window-height-on-resize/27449952#comment43338243_27449727) in the comments.

```
.adjustedHeight {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I was also able to get it working with overflow-y: auto. That way the scrollbar didn't appear unless it had to. According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) the default is "visible", so both scroll and auto should take care of it.